# Dressing a mannequin with different items in android

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to implement similar screen. Unable to add different items at proper place. I want to add shoes at the proper place.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:padding="0dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBody"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/dress" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFeet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgBody"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_shoe1"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFace"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_head"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Constraint Layout it will be easy for you to Design your Requirement

Add this dependency in your Project

```
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Here I have added a code for your design

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="55dip"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Center" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Review"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="265dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="463dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Try to user Table layout for split a screen in two part. like below :
>   Here i have use android:layout_weight="0.5" for screen size.

```
   <TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#EBEBEB"
    android:stretchColumns="2"
    android:weightSum="2">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!--Write your xml Right side xml code here-->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <!--Write your xml Left side xml code here-->

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of layout you should try to use canvas in left preview screen. On selecting any item should update left canvas by adding item in canvas and rendering elements.

Please have a look over [canvas and drawing images over canvas](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/drawables).